# Is it possible to match NULL values with the IN operator? (x IN (NULL, a, b))

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I remove Nulls in a column in a delete statement, that also uses IN?

Here is the following line, and all records with a STATUS (column name btw) in the string are being removed. Except the records with a NULL STATUS column.

```
DELETE FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE [STATUS] IN (NULL,'09','12','13','A1','C1','H1','J1','S1','T1');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot include NULL in the IN clause. Think of the IN expanding to a series of ORs, so you'd have:

```
...WHERE [STATUS] = NULL OR [STATUS] = '09'...
```

which will not give what you're expecting. Instead, treat the NULL condition independent of the rest:

```
DELETE FROM PRODUCTS 
    WHERE [STATUS] IS NULL
        OR [STATUS] IN ('09','12','13','A1','C1','H1','J1','S1','T1');
```

Comment: I'm not buying "because it expands to a series of ORs": it could have been "expanded" to `x IS NULL OR x = '12' OR ...` and still met that condition. The real reason deals with the defined SQL semantics (and how they are [properly] implemented), despite how it can be "alternatively viewed". But, +1 otherwise :)

Comment: I'm not buying, "is not valid": it is indeed valid, just not the result the OP was hoping for.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Agreed. Probably a poor choice of words on my part.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
COALESCE(STATUS IN (...),TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that because `IN` uses `=` and you need `IS` to check for `NULL`. Just do it separately:

```
DELETE FROM PRODUCTS
    WHERE STATUS IS NULL
    OR STATUS IN ('09','12','13','A1','C1','H1','J1','S1','T1');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't include a match with NULL like this.
Instead, include a separate WHERE clause:

```
DELETE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE [STATUS IS NULL] OR [STATUS] IN ('09','12','13','A1','C1','H1','J1','S1','T1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
  FROM products
 WHERE COALESCE(STATUS, '09') 
          IN ('09', '12', '13', 'A1', 'C1', 'H1', 'J1', 'S1', 'T1');
```